# Making a single column data frame from 2D dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a data frame which has shape (7500, 2000) consisting of values from 0 to 7.

```
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 1990    1991    1992    1993    1994    1995    1996    1997    1998    1999
0   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
1   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
2   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
3   0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 ... 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0
```

I want to create a data frame from it, where there is one column.

The value is a number which has maximum count of a number 1-7, since most of them are zeros, so, I would appreciate if the logic to be as following.

1. Fill zero only there where count of zeroes = 95%
2. Fill with the maximum count of any number 1-7 where zeroes are less than 95% of total.

Comment: "Fill with the maximum count of any number 1-7" means that you want the count of the single most counted digits, or the aggregated sum of all numbers different from 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following. Using the following example dataframe:

```
print(df)

  1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
0                                                  
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  0.0  1.0  2.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0

def fun(x):
    is_zero = x.quantile(q=0.95) == 0
    if is_zero:
        return x
    else:
        most_common = x[x!=0].value_counts().index[0]
        return np.repeat(most_common, len(x))

df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis = 1)

    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
0                                                  
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0  1.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on the excellent answer from Alexandre, I am not sure if he interpreted your question correctly.

If you need to build a new dataframe containing a single column (or want to attach that column to the existing dataframe), I provide the solution below:

```
df = original_dataframe

def fun(x):
    is_zero = x.quantile(q=0.95) == 0
    if is_zero:
        return 0
    else:
        number = x[x != 0].value_counts()
        return number[number.index[0]]

# to add a new column to the existing dataset
df["new_column"] = df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis = 1) 

# to build a new dataframe
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(df.apply(lambda x: fun(x), axis = 1))
```